# Override document.location.href is it possible in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override somehow document.location.href ?

need override getter, ex.: alert(document.location.href); should return lets say "www.example.com" while real document location is www.stackoverflow.com...

don't know is it possible..

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us what you actually want to achieve, a solution might be forthcoming.  The best way to do what you seem to have asked for is alert("www.example.com");

Comment: I believe his website uses plug-ins, which shouldn't have access to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

No, but...

In Ecmascript 5, there is support for getters/setters and you can spoof the `document` reference if accessed from within a scope which redefines it.

Proof:

```
(function (document) {
    alert(document);        // -> "spoofed document" 
})("spoofed document");
```

Combined with [accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Defining_Getters_and_Setters) you can replace the document object. (Javascript 1.5 is needed for accessors.)

Comment: Note that it's still easy to break out of this sandbox using various commands which perform an `eval()` internally or directly using `eval()`. For an example see here: http://jsbin.com/esula/edit

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: gs: You could set up a fake Facebook sign-in page and the change the URL onload.

Comment: This actually depends on the browser. Some browsers will allow you to replace the location object and fake the return from this API. Websites should not rely upon this object as a means of protecting from attack.

Comment: There's no connection between the javascript variables and the URL. Returning wrong data from `document.location` doesn't affect the URL field of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As others already have noted it is not possible to change the URL without reloading the page.

Note that you can the change the fragment identifier, i.e. the part in the URL after the hash (#) using document.location.hash, but that is probably not good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Swap out "document" to another variable, edit it, and swap it back in.

```
var d = {}
for (var k in document) {
    d[k] = document[k];
}
d["location"]="out of this world";
document = d;
```

Comment: Assignment to `document` has no effect (unless if you `var document`, but that's not what you want anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can override it in IE7 or IE8 by making use of independent script tags (but not in modern Firefox or IE9+):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var _oldDoc = document; // IE < 9 won't work with the code below unless we place it here in its own script tag
</script>
<script>
var document = {};
for (var k in _oldDoc) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || 
        !k.match(/^(location|domain|body)$/) // Cause problems or errors in Mozilla, but Mozilla isn't really creating a new document object anyways
    ) {
        document[k] = _oldDoc[k];
    }
}

// Causes problems in Mozilla as we can't get Mozilla to actually overwrite the object
document["location"] = {
    href: "out of this world",
    toString: function () {
        return this.href;
    }
};
alert(document.location.href); // "out of this world" in IE < 9
alert(document.location); // "out of this world" in IE < 9
alert(document.title); // 'Some title'
</script>
<script>
alert(document.location.href); // also "out of this world" in IE < 9
alert(document.location); // also gives "out of this world" in IE < 9
alert(document.title); // also 'Some title'
</script>

</body>
</html>
```