# Phonegap - HTML files that don't include .htm/.html in the filename

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, cordova

Using Phonegap it is trivial to programmatically switch from one page to another using code along the lines of:

```
window.location.href = "someDestination.html";
```

However, I've noticed that for some reason, this will not work if the extension on the destination file is not '.html'.  For example, the following code:

```
window.location.href = "someOtherDestination";
```

...will cause PhoneGap to fail with the following error message:

> Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted

I would have thought that PhoneGap would be intelligent enough to inspect the contents of the destination file to determine if it is a valid webpage (for instance, by looking for a `<html>` tag), rather than attempting to rely on superfluous information like the file extension.  But this doesn't seem to be the case.

So my question is, why does PhoneGap care whether or not the filename ends in `.htm`/`.html`, and how do I make it stop caring about this?

Answer (score 2):

LOL:

```
function getHTMLFile(str) {
    return str + '.html';
}

function getHTMFile(str) {
    return str + '.htm';
}
```

;-)

No, but seriously this is part of the window.location.href's spec. It's not a PhoneGap specific issue. You will not be able to override this simply with javascript (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042810/override-document-location-href-is-it-possible-in-javascript)).

Comment: How do you mean it's 'part of the spec'?  Nothing prevents you from saying `window.location.href = '/someServlet/someAction';` when you want to redirect the browser to some dynamic HTML content.  And it works just as well if you have some static HTML content in a `somePage` file, so long as the hosting server sets the response content-type to `text/html` by default.  It follows that the exact same approach should work when referring to local resources.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this  Cordova/Phonegap 3.0

Near the top of my page I had a redirect.  Not "responsive design", I know, but a good temporary fix for showing a UI that fits in an iPhone.

```
<script>
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod).*AppleWebKit/i)) {
    window.location = "iphone/";
  }
</script>
```

Failed with the same error.  Changing it to

```
window.location = "iphone/index.html";
```

fixed the error