# Can Javascript's "document" object be used as a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, object, document

I was wondering if I can add to Javascript's `document` object. Like:

```
var document = {
    name: "My Name"   
}
```

- Is that legal in JavaScript?
- If it is, is it considered "good practice", or should I avoid it?
- If I define it as a variable, is it then considered as a unique object, and not a JS DOM object?

I am plenty new to JavaScript and any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

After some conversation in the comments and a little more thought on it, I really want to know if I can manipulate the `document` variable and still use `document` for normal use.

Comment: Javascript as a language doesn't care about `document`. It's just another variable that happens to be pre-set by web browsers. Right? And since you're creating a new object that is not a `DOMElement` then no it won't be a JS DOM object any more. And why would this ever be "good practice"?

Comment: Is it? Kind of like `navigator` is?

Comment: Sure. The spec's chapter 15 tells us what the pre-defined objects are, and `document` isn't one of them. Remember, Javascript _as a language_ isn't inherently bound to web browsers.

Comment: Well, it seems a lot of people are very picky about "good practice". In other words, if there would be any reason to avoid doing something, then just *don't do it*.

Comment: If you create such a variable on the global scope, you'll be unable to manipulate the DOM, unless you keep a reference to the original.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can agree with that rule in the general case, but certainly in this one I can't see any reason why you'd confuse yourself and other code maintainers by overwriting `document` with something non-conventional.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- **Yes** you **can** do that
- **No** you **shouldn't** do that

`document` is just another property of the `global` / `window` object. If you declare it as formal parameter or *variable* within a scope, the lookup process will match that *name* first in that scope you declared it, so it kinda overlaps it.

Regardless, you don't want to do it, why would you ? Its so confusing for you and anybody else who is looking at your code. Its **very bad practice**.

Actually, that is the reason why *most* "advanced" javascript snippets / libraries begin with a closured *function scope* like

```
(function( window, document, undefined ) {
    // window will always reference the "window" object that got originally passed in
    // document will always reference the "document" object that got originally passed in
    // undefined will always reference the "undefined value" that got originally passed in
}( window, window.document ));
```

..just to avoid, the such called *asshole effect*. If such a *closure* is openend at the very top of a file, it makes sure that you reference the *original* objects within, just in case some genius had the great idea to overwrite/overlap them.

> Conclusion: You are of course free to choose the name of your
>   variables at will, but you really shouldn't use the name of such
>   prominent names like `window`, `document`, `undefined` et cetera for
>   obvious reasons.

Comment: "Code" in this context is an uncountable noun and, as such, "codes" is incorrect.

Comment: Hehe +1 The first time I heard of the *asshole effect*. And I like your answer, this is what I wanted to know.

Comment: Given this best answer, it's still important to note that the DOM is extensible for good reason, so don't just categorically rule it out. Many important changes to the DOM are first rolled out by individuals, long before the standards catch up. Most popular libraries make great use of the DOM's extensibility.

Answer (score 6):

What you say you're doing - adding to the `document` object - is not what your code is actually doing.

What you **are** doing is *redifining* `document`. If you want to add to it then use the following:

```
document.name = "My Name"
```

This way you can still use `document`. However, it's still generally bad practice - you can just use a different object instead of document:

```
myObject = {name:"My Name"};
```

Then `myObject` is still global. Modifying the `document` object can have unfortunate side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

As I indicated in comments, the ECMAScript spec chapter 15 tell us which objects are built-in; `document` isn't one of them.

It's just a variable set by your web browser when you use Javascript in that context and, as such, you can overwrite it to your heart's content with a `DOMElement` object, or some other kind of object, or whatever you like.

However, this is a bad idea for all the obvious reasons.

You can probably *add* properties to the `document` object without being quite so confusing, but I still can't think of any reason to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can augment or modify any object that comes out of the box in JS or a given browser.

Even:
   var Object = {
      name: "Trevor"
    };
    console.log(Object);

Will log: Object {name: "Trevor"} even though pretty much everything is made out of Objects in JS.

No, terrible practice, however.

Answer (score 2):

the document variable is a global variable representing the current page you are viewing (in a sense).

even though it is not in the [reserved keywords of javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), you shouldn't use it as such, because you can override the document object ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042810/override-document-location-href-is-it-possible-in-javascript) ) (although not as simple as you are trying to), then you will override the reference to the old one and have a bad time.

So yes, you can do it, no you shouldn't. It is bad practice. Try to pick a different name, that way someone that takes over your code won't be lost (or angry at you!)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is not a good idea, read this [article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

You can overwrite things on accident. You can increase the performance overhead required. And you have to be careful because different browsers will behave differently.

Comment: Sorry but links aren't answers; SO is a Q&A not an index

Comment: The answer guidelines say that if you post a link you should also post an overview of what is contained, in case the link dies in the future.