# JavaScript: Prevent execution of javascript:-URIs assigned to location.href

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I am currently developing a webextension (Firefox:latest) for myself which blocks/catches functions, which are able to evaluate and execute a string as javascript-code (e.g., eval, Function constructor, setTimeout).

So far the extension works as intended, with the exception of javascript:-URIs being assigned to location/location.href.

For example:

```
location.href = "javascript:alert('Hello there')";
```

Since the location object is non-configurable, I cannot rewrite it (e.g., set to null) or define a setter for it.

I am aware, that "Content-Security-Policy" (without allowing `unsafe-inline`) is able to block this, but using CSP this way also blocks every other instance of inline-code (e.g., code between script-tags).
I'd like to avoid this, since it requires every 
    `<script>...</script>` to be reinserted with, e.g., a nonce.

This brings me to my question:
Is there a way to block/catch this kind of code-execution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override document.location.href is it possible in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042810/override-document-location-href-is-it-possible-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you wish to prevent execution of Javascript for a simple link which has its `href` attribute set to `javascript:alert('Hello there')`.

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello there')">Click me</a>
```

One  of the approaches to avoid this is to simply select all such links, and reset the `href` attributes - to something harmless, such as `javascript:void(0)`.

In the snippet below, I am using the attribute selector to select all elements which have `href` value that begins with `javascript`.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="javascript:"]');

for (var idx = 0; idx < elems.length; idx++) {
  elems[idx].href = "javascript:void(0)";
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello there')">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This is a nice idea to deal with javascript:-URIs in link-elements. 
However, I am looking for a solution to block code execution via the `location`-object (which is not a HTMLElement).

Comment: @user9131077 I am not sure what you are referring to. It is not the location object which is responsible for execution of javascript. It is the URL. For example, if you copy and paste the following in URL bar, it would give you the alert: `javascript:alert('Hello there')`

Comment: You are of course correct, that the location object itself is not  executing the script, but the "mechanisms" executed, once the browser loads such a URL (e.g., when the location-object gets such a url assigned). Sorry for the misleading phrasing in the prev. comment.. 
However, do you, by chance, know a way to prevent such URLs from being executed?